# Force my tabitem to calcultate its width

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following style for my tabitems :

```
<Style x:Key="BoutonMenuHaut" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                        <Border Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" CornerRadius="0" Name="border">
                            <Grid>
                                <ContentPresenterVerticalAlignment="Center"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            TextBlock.Foreground="{StaticResource CouleurTexteBoutonsHaut}"
                            TextBlock.FontSize="{DynamicResource FontSizeBig}"
                            Name="textTab" 
                            ContentSource="Header" Margin="10,0,60,0"
                            RecognizesAccessKey="True">
                                </ContentPresenter>
                                <Rectangle Height="2" x:Name="separation" Fill="Red" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

As you can see I bind the fontsize to a value defined like this :

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
<sys:Double x:Key="FontSizeBig">16</sys:Double>
```

And in the window_sizechanged event I do this :

```
this.Resources["FontSizeBig"] = TextSizeFromResolution(12, height);
```

where height is the height of the screen.

But when I resize my window my tabitem doesn't resize itself and i'm not able to see all my tabs in the page anymore.

So my question is : How can I force the tabcontrol to resize the tabitems when the size changes ? (because the size of the text has changed so the tabitem's width should change too.
I've tried InvalidateMeasure, Update Layout... but I could not manage to make it work.

Could you help me ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You could bind the width of the tabs to the ActualWidth of the tab control with a converter:

```
          <Style TargetType="TabItem">
          <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding    
                  Path=ActualWidth,  Converter={StaticResource YourConverter},  
                 RelativeSource={RelativeSource   
                FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}"/>
          </Style>
```

Comment: If I do each tabitem will take the full width of the window ?

Comment: No, you must write your own converter. This converter receives the ActualWidth of your TabControl and returns the desired width of the tabitems. You can return any value, e.g. you can devide the ActualWidth of the TabControl by 5 or something like that and return that value for your TabItems. Please look up IValueConverter. It is not very complicated.